# Inherited field does not exist in odoo

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-15

I am working on a custom addon for the sales quotation form in odoo 15 while inheriting the sale.order.template model. I am trying to add a new field next to the quantity field but i keep getting a "Field [field-name] does not exist error" in relation to my views file.
Here is the code in my views file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
<record id="sales_quotation_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">sale.order.template.form.inherit</field>
<field name="model">sale.order.template</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_management.sale_order_template_view_form"/>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_order_template_line_ids']/form[@string='Quotation Template Lines']/group/group[1]/div/field[@name='product_uom_qty']" positon="after">
     <field name='price'/>
     </xpath>
</field>
</record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

And my model.py code:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class SalesQuotation(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.template"
    price = fields.Many2one(string='Unit Price')
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what may be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your new field is a `Many2one`.
You need to specify which table it refers to i.e.:

`price = fields.Many2one('other.table...', string='Unit Price')`

Also can't you just use a `float` field? In any case I would test with a plain `float` field first.

Comment: I don't think it is the solution for his problem, but yes many2one for a price field seems wrong. I will upvote anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

Your view extension seems to change something on the lines of sale templates. So your model extension is done for the wrong model. Extend `sale.order.template.line` instead:

```py
from odoo import models, fields

class SaleOrderTemplateLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.template.line"
    price = fields.Float(string='Unit Price')
```

Oh and shouldn't a price be a float? I already changed that in my code example.

Comment: That's probably it. OP is accessing fields in the line.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to solve the problems:

**The view inheritance**

1. Make sure your custom module depends on `sale_management` module where `sale.order.template` is defined:

****manifest**.py**

```
...
'depends': ['sale_management'],
...
```

2. Simplify the `xpath`:

```
...
<xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_order_template_line_ids']/form//field[@name='product_uom_qty']" positon="after">
    <field name='price' />
</xpath>
...
```

**Model**

Change your code to be like this:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class SalesQuotation(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.template"
    price = fields.Float(string='Unit Price')
```

Comment: And here the same: good points, really, but not solving the problem.